# Google drive handling

Tags: model-view-controller, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive, fileshare

Hello programmers I am new in API integration I am wiling to develop a file sharing Asp.net MVC application with Google drive API. I have a idea of file upload, download and delete options but how can a user share any file by selecting from Grid (Grid which show user's files via Google drive Api) and that shared file would be add in another page of my Application from where any user can download that shared file.

Answer (score 0):

#### You might benefit from taking a look at Google Drive Picker.

Google Picker is a file manager widget that you may use to access data stored on Google servers. The Google Picker API can be used to allow users to open or upload Google Drive files.

I suggest you take a look at the examples displayed in this article [here](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs).

#### Reference

- [Google Drive Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not the case .I mean i would make a Google drive picker or will show the files on grid but the user will share there file by one click "Share File" and i am unable to understand how to do it.